# Different CAN-BUS specs on the same bus

Tags: can, canopen

I have several questions about different combinations of CAN-Bus nodes that are able to work together with realiability:

1. CAN2.0A and CAN2.0B nodes can work on the same bus at the SAME speed?
2. CAN2.0A and CAN2.0B nodes can work on the same bus at different speed? for instance 250kbps and 500kbps
3. CANopen id. 11 bits and CAN2.0A and CAN2.0B at 500 kbps on the same bus?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. No. 3. Same question as 1)

Answer (score 4):

1. CAN 2.0B is backwards compatible with CAN 2.0A. But CAN 2.0A controllers have to support the *2.0B passive* feature to be compatible; otherwise a 2.0B message will flag an error.
2. No, the CAN bitrates must be the same for all CAN nodes.
3. CANopen is implemented on top of the CAN *Physical* and *Data Link* layers. So, they're at least compatible on these two lower OSI layers. For upper layer compatibility, you have to ensure that the arbitration field (CAN: *Message ID*; CANopen: *Function Code + Node ID*) doesn't conflict.